# How to temporary pause function execution?

Tags: swift, pause, suspend

I want to make very simple animation by going through emoji one by one

```
func pickingAnimation() {
        for _ in 1...10 {
            currentEmoji.text = randomEmoji().rawValue 
            //currentEmoji - UILabel
            //randomEmoji() generates a random emoji
        }
```

Is there any function that adds a temporary pause to function execution, so user could see that emoji are changing? Like wait(1) or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` and a recursive function call.

As a basic example, try this in a playground (and watch the console!):

```
func printNumbers(current: Int, limit: Int) {
    print(current)
    if current < limit {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            printNumbers(current: current + 1, limit: limit)
        }
    }
}
printNumbers(current: 1, limit: 10)
```

The point is that between the `print` statements, nothing is happening. We are not waiting, which would be bad (we'd be block the main thread); literally nothing is happening. So if what you do, instead of `print`, is display something in the interface, it is in fact displayed.